# R gt how to center column headers

Tags: r, gt

I would like to center column headers using the gt package. It seems gt assigns the same alignment to the header as the body of the table in each column.

In the example below, can I center the 'cyl' column header while its values are right-aligned? Is there a column header adjustment function like the one I'm using for bolding the header font?

```
mtcars %>% 
  select(mpg, cyl, disp) %>% 
  gt() %>% 
  cols_width(cyl ~px(150)) %>% 
  cols_align(align = c("right"), columns = 2) %>% 
  tab_options(column_labels.font.weight = "bold")
```

[image: How to center the header column 2?]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `tab_style()` function to format specific locations in the table:

```
library(dplyr)
library(gt)

mtcars %>% 
  select(mpg, cyl, disp) %>% 
  head(5) %>%
  gt() %>% 
  cols_width(cyl ~px(150)) %>% 
  cols_align(align = "right", columns = cyl) %>% 
  tab_options(column_labels.font.weight = "bold") %>%
  tab_style(
    style = cell_text(align = "center"),
    locations = cells_column_labels(columns = cyl))
```

[image]